# Split a Pandas Dataframe into multiple Dataframes based on Triangular Number Series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I have a DataFrame (df) and I need to split it into n number of Dataframes based on the column numbers. But, it has to follow the Triangular Series pattern:

```
df1 = df[[0]]
df2 = df[[1,2]] 
df3 = df[[3,4,5]]
df4 = df[[6,7,8,9]]
```

etc.

Comment: can you post some sample data? Also can you let us know what you have already tried? And for each dataframe, the number of columns should be 1 longer than the last? and how many columns do you have? If you add more detail it will help us, help you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.arange(100).reshape(10, 10),
    columns=list('ABCDEFGHIJ')
)

df

    A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J
0   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
1  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19
2  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29
3  30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39
4  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49
5  50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59
6  60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69
7  70  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79
8  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89
9  90  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99

i_s, j_s = np.arange(4).cumsum(), np.arange(1, 5).cumsum()

df1, df2, df3, df4 = [
    df.iloc[:, i:j] for i, j in zip(i_s, j_s)
]
```

---

**Verify**

```
pd.concat(dict(enumerate([df.iloc[:, i:j] for i, j in zip(i_s, j_s)])), axis=1)

    0   1       2           3            
    A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J
0   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
1  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19
2  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29
3  30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39
4  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49
5  50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59
6  60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69
7  70  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79
8  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89
9  90  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99
```

Answer (score 0):

first get Triangular Number Series, then apply it to dataframe

```
n = len(df.columns.tolist())
end = 0
i = 0
res = []
while end < n:
 begin = end
 end = i*(i+1)/2
 res.append(begin,end)

idx = map( lambda x:range(x),res)
for i in idx:
 df[i]
```